# Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (1500,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis

**i am getting an error only in the fitting part.
is there an issue with x_train and y-train?**

```
 import keras
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(input_dim=1500,init="random_uniform",activation='sigmoid',output_dim=1000))#input layer
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=100,init="random_uniform",activation='sigmoid'))#hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=1,init='random_uniform',activation='sigmoid'))#output layer
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])#adam=batch gradent descent
    model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=50,batch_size=10)#epochs no of iteration
    y_pred =  model.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, your `x_train` should be a vector of shape `(1500,)` 
 as you have given `input_dim=1500` in your first layer but looks like you are passing the `x_train` vector with shape `(1,)`. **You have to correct the shape of x_train you are passing to the model**.

Show the code where you are reading the data and storing it as `x_train`. That will help to see where the error is.